# How to get curl command output into variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to take output of following command one variable and then want to get e`mail id` and `id` in two variables.

Code

```
curl -s -b ${COOKIE_FILE} -c ${COOKIE_FILE} 'https://api.xxxx.xxxx.com/sso/user?email='${USER_EMAIL} |python -m json.tool
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "createdAt": "2017-12-08T11:07:15.000Z",
        "email": "vxxx.sxxx@domain.com",
        "gravatarUrl": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/13656",
        "id": 937,
        "updatedAt": "2017-12-08T11:07:15.000Z",
        "username": "339cba4c-d90c-11e7-bc18-005056ba0d15"
    }
]
```

one more, if `USER_EMAIL` is wrong then we get output as `[]` then I have to print `Email ID is not present` and I will exit code `exit -1`

I am python developer, doing scripting first time

Comment: You should be using `jq` instead of regular unix tools like grep, sed, awk etc.

Comment: `-1` would be an unusual exit code. Exit codes indicating failure are between 1 and 255 (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id=$(cat output | grep -w "id" | awk -F ':' {'print $2'} | sed -e 's|[," ]||g'); echo $id
```

Do the same for email.
Or second way like anubhava suggest in comment, using jq. ( Probably you will need to install jq first , apt-get install jq ). And then:

```
cat output | jq '.[].email'
```

Comment: can you add how to get output in `output` variable. I try but it say me ` output: command not found
No JSON object could be decoded
`

Comment: I put your result in to a file with name “output”. You can add “>output” at the end of your first command with curl , and then read this file like in my example .

Answer (score 1):

Use jq to parse json:

```
$ cat input
[
    {
        "createdAt": "2017-12-08T11:07:15.000Z",
        "email": "vxxx.sxxx@domain.com",
        "gravatarUrl": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/13656",
        "id": 937,
        "updatedAt": "2017-12-08T11:07:15.000Z",
        "username": "339cba4c-d90c-11e7-bc18-005056ba0d15"
    }
]
$ jq -r '.[] | (.email,.id)' input
vxxx.sxxx@domain.com
937
$ read email id << EOF
> $(jq -r '.[] | (.email,.id)' input | tr \\n ' ')
> EOF
$ echo $email
vxxx.sxxx@domain.com
$ echo $id
937
```

To check if email was valid, you can do things like:

```
echo "${email:?}"
```

or

```
test -z "$email" && exit 1
```